# vue 3 chart js chart is undefined in click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I am currently trying to upgrade my site to vue 3 from vue 2 and as part of this, I have had to updgrade vue-chartjs from version 4 to 5 and it seems to have broken my click event.

Previously I had the chart on my page like so:

```
<bar v-if="loaded"
   ref="chart"
   :data="chartData"
   :options="chartOptions">
</bar>

import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs';
```

And I could use the following in my options click event:

```
onClick: event => {
    const chart = this.$refs.chart._data._chart;
    const activeElement = chart.getElementAtEvent(event)[0];
}
```

Since I have upgraded, `_data` is now undefined, so I tried to get the chart object by doing `this.$refs.chart.chart`, but now I get the following error:

> chart.getElementAtEvent is not a function

Does anyone know how to get the chart so I can call the `getElementAtEvent` - or if this is still the correct function to get the label from the bar that is clicked on?

[Current code stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ofrpcb-fwj7cl?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [V3 migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.2.1/migration/v3-migration.html#removal-of-public-apis)

`getElementAtEvent` is replaced with `chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(e, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, false)`

working sandbox link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ofrpcb-srknqa?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - I didn't realise I had gone up 2 versions of chart.js